# Canvas setLineDash and lineDashOffset NOT resetting in iOS/Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, safari

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mYdm9/4/

On my PC, doing

```
ctx.lineWidth=20;
ctx.setLineDash([20,30]); 
ctx.lineDashOffset=10;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150,150);
ctx.lineTo(240,240);
ctx.lineTo(180,40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath()
```

Gives the first set of lines, with the desired dashes/offsets

Now with

```
ctx.setLineDash([0,0]); 
ctx.lineDashOffset=0
```

in the next batch of commands:

```
ctx.beginPath();
//resets line dash... except on iOS Safari it seems...
ctx.setLineDash([0,0]); 
ctx.lineDashOffset=0;
ctx.moveTo(0,300);
ctx.lineTo(0,250);
ctx.lineTo(100,400);
ctx.lineTo(200,300);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath()
```

After the first set of lines seems to reset any dash properties. Get solid lines again

On an iPad2 running Safari...  it seems completely ignored, the lines stay dashed. Why is this? Also, is there some other method to properly resetting line dashes...? (preferably working cross browser/OS)

Thanks

Comment: I think there is no support for `setLineDash` on mobile safari (iOS), at least in 6.x

Answer (score 18):

Use this notation, it will work in all browsers that supports setLineDash

```
ctx.setLineDash([]);
```

Comment: Thanx! Worked like a charm, had the same issue as OP, now the issue is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similair behaviour, the only way to make Safari reset the lineDash was to use **context.restore()**.

Adding

```
ctx.restore();
```

before drawing your non-dashed lines will work.

You will then have to reset other things like lineWidth off course.